# read xbee network traffic on xbee hooked to computer

Tags: xbee

I have a bunch of equipment that communicate with each other using xbee series 1 radios.  I'd like to read that traffic from this network on my computer (which has an xbee hooked to it's USB port).  Using XCTU, I can read the traffic for a particular xbee in the network by setting MY in my computer's xbee to the MY of the particular xbee.  But what I'd really like to do is read traffic from all of the xbees.  How would I configure my xbee to do that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an 802.15.4 packet sniffer to monitor the 802.15.4 network traffic.  It isn't possible to sniff traffic with the XBee module itself.

If you're on a budget, various manufacturers have free software that works with their 802.15.4 dongles.  For example, Texas Instruments has [sniffer software](http://www.ti.com/tool/PACKET-SNIFFER) that works with a [$49 USB dongle](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2531emk).